# Fast value checking?

Tags: c, database, optimization, hiredis

I have a list of 50,000,000+ 512-bit values.

I have a stream of data coming in at 1,750,000 values per second, I need to check if each of those values is in the aforementioned list or not.

Currently I've opted for redis via hiredis in c using the EXISTS command on keys. It's quite fast and I'm managing to check ~160,000 values per second.

However, I really need to do this 10* faster as it's causing a bottleneck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) might be useful to screen out values that are definitely not in the list, assuming the majority of values in the input stream are not present in the list.